# Android SetingActivity ListPreferences Load Values from Array

Tags: android, android-activity, settings

Is it possible to load an String-list or HashMap into a ListPreference inside a SettingsActivity or do I need to start a whole knew activity?

And if, how can I register a click onto an Item inside a SettingsActivity?

note: I want to load a HashMap, the List should show the key value and if the user clicks on the Item, he should edit the value behind the key value. There also will be an "add" button so the user can add new keys and values by himself.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, that I need to start a new activity from my SettingsActivity.
I did this by creating a new Activity and adding this to my preferencex.xml:

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="@string/pref_color_picker"
    android:key="pref_key_color_picker">

    <Preference android:title="@string/default_colors">
        <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetPackage="my.package.app"
            android:targetClass="my.package.app.theActivity"/>

    </Preference>

</PreferenceCategory>
```